# angular reactive form pattern validator only allow text, numbers and some characters

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am using angular 10 and reactive forms.
I need a input to only accept (letters, numbers, and this 2 characters "_" and "-")
I've tried letters and numbers with this:

```
 Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ][0-9]*')]
```

The above only works if I do it this way:

```
Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')]
```

But I also need it to allow numbers and - and _

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Your code become

```
Validators.pattern('[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*')]
```

Edit:
Based on comments by @ekalin

Comment: Seems to be accepting special characters... full line is: name: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.min(10), Validators.max(30), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z0-9 -_]*')] ]

Comment: The regex is allowing all characters between space (ascii 32) and _ (ascii 137), so almost everything. The - must be the first (or maybe also last) character to not represent a range, so I'd use `[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*`.

Comment: Sorry Luis...your's didn't work for me as it was accepting character I didn't want accepted but your's worked @ekalin ...

Comment: Ohh. I will delete my answare and @ekalin will post it answare. I just test it on regex101 webpage